# Error while trying to launch Pig script with JAVA

Tags: java, hadoop, bigdata, apache-pig

I'm trying to launch a pig script from JAVA. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.pig.ExecType;
import org.apache.pig.PigServer;
import org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException;


public class pigCV {


public static void main(String args[]){

    PigServer pigServer;
    try {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("fs.default.name", "hdfs://hdfs://localhost:8022");
        props.setProperty("mapred.job.tracker", "localhost:8021");

        pigServer = new PigServer(ExecType.MAPREDUCE, props);

        pigServer.registerScript("Desktop/text_v3.pig");

    } 
    catch (ExecException e) {   e.printStackTrace(); } 
    catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

}


}
```

But some exceptions are thrown:

> 2013-05-23 01:34:54,666 ERROR [main] conf.Configuration(1151): Failed to set 
>   setXIncludeAware(true) for parser  org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl@1787038:java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:  This parser does not support specification "null" version "null"
>       java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This parser does not support specification "null" version "null"
>       at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setXIncludeAware(DocumentBuilderFactory.java:590)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:1149)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:1125)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:1064)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.get(Configuration.java:424)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.checkAndWarnDeprecation(JobConf.java:1709)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.(JobConf.java:164)
>       at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.init(HExecutionEngine.java:169)
>       at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.init(HExecutionEngine.java:137)
>       at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.connect(PigContext.java:200)
>       at org.apache.pig.PigServer.(PigServer.java:169)
>       at org.apache.pig.PigServer.(PigServer.java:158)
>       at org.apache.pig.PigServer.(PigServer.java:154)
>       at pigCV.main(pigCV.java:21)

Do you have any idea to help me ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have a(n old) `Xerces` implementation in your classpath.
Try to set

```
-Djavax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=
   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
```

(in Eclipse: VM argument) or in code:

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory",
  "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl");
```

Remark:
There's probably a typo in `fs.default.name` : Shouldn't it be `hdfs://localhost:8022` instead of `hdfs://hdfs://localhost:8022` ?